# How to vertically align text inside flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm creating portfolio and have a links as buttons done as flexbox so that responsivity is done easier.
Also height of these flexboxes is done using JavaScript due to having percentages.

I've already tried other advices, but none of them were this exact.
I've tried using

```html
justify-content:center
align-self:center
vertical-align:center
```

Currently I'm using Ubuntu 19.04, text editor Atom and PHP 7.2.17

Code here
https://codepen.io/fTc_CZ/pen/joGYJr

I expected the text to align to the center of the square not to the top of it.

Comment: add the flex to your square class with align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set line-height to be the same as height on the same class.
example from your code:

```
'height': cw + 'px',
'line-height': cw + 'px' // Use same as height
```